# How can I use an Android app specific folder under documents?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want people to be able to upload and download the files for my app to use (e.g. by plugging the device into a PC and using the file manager), so to me creating an app specific folder under documents seems to be the simplest way to do this. I'm currently using the standard external files folder, but it's not very user friendly if people need to find that each time. I also don't want to make the user create the folder, as I want it to be consistent for all users (and so that the app knows where to find things and create new files).

Firstly, am I allowed to do this?

Secondly, how do I do this?

I have tried various permutations, based around the code below, but none seem to create the folder.

```
var defaultPath = File("/sdcard/Documents/MyApp/").toString()

if(!File(defaultPath).exists()) {
    val docsPath = File(defaultPath)
    docsPath.mkdirs()
}
```

Could it be a permissions issue? If so, how do I solve that?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be using Shared Storage: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: Yes you can create such a folder with mkdir(). Just like you create ant folder. Or the file manager on the pc can do it. What is/are the problem(s)?